# Why Box always returns 20003 BoxSDK Error at the first login?

Tags: ios, swift, box

When I try to do an authentication by calling: `BOXContentClient.default().authenticate`, for the first time, the  Box login view controller appears -as expected-:

[image]

but after inserting a valid email address/password, I'm getting the following error:

> BOXContentSDKAuthErrorAccessTokenNonceMismatch = 20003, Operation
>   failed because nonce returned by server didn't match the one used by
>   app to authorize user

The `BOXUser` -at the `completionBlock`- returned as `nil`.

However, this behavior appears for the first time *only*, if I recalled the authentication function (second time), it works as expected without displaying login view controller Box (`BOXUser` is not `nil` and there is no error, i.e `Error` is nil)

Here is my authentication method:

```
func boxLogin(completionHandler: @escaping Completion){
    BOXContentClient.default().authenticate(completionBlock: { (BOXUser, Error) in
        if Error == nil {
            print("\(String(describing: BOXUser))")

            let boxAccessToken = BOXContentClient.default().session.accessToken
            let boxRefreshToken = BOXContentClient.default().oAuth2Session.refreshToken

            // after the first call it works as expected...
            //...
        } else {
            //... it reaches here for the first call...
        }
    })  
}
```

Why do I have to call `BOXContentClient.default().authenticate` twice?